# Add extra information to laravel ->get() for each result

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an 'artists' table and a 'performances' table. The performances table has a performance time field which is a timestamp.

When returning my artists data, I also do a relationship to get the performances:

```
$artists = Artist::with('performances', 'performances.stage')->get();
```

What I now want to do however is also add another bit of information to the performances relationship which will show the time till the performance using the performance time field.

I use the field data elsewhere in a different format so don't want to use a mutator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a mutator. Let's say your `Performance` model has a `time` field.

```
public function getModifiedTimeAttribute() {
    return $this->time . ' and something else!';
}
```

which you'd access as `$performance->modified_time`. By default, this made-up field won't exist in Laravel's array/JSON output of the model, but you can add this to the model to make it show up there:

```
protected $appends = ['modified_time'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic Attribute in your `Performance` Model, like so:

```
class Performance extends Model
{
    [...]

    public function getTimeToNextAttribute()
    {
        //calculate Time to next Performance and return it
    }
}
```

You can then access this property via $performance->time_to_next.